# USB to HDMI via a hub does not work

Tags: windows, usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi, device-manager

I purchased an [HP 250 G8](https://support.hp.com/ca-en/document/c06951526) Windows 11 laptop  this year.  For video output there is just one HDMI port on the laptop. My goal is to be able to connect and use two separate monitors.

In order to extend and use more than one monitor, I have tried to connect two different hubs / docking stations with HDMI outputs to various USB ports on the laptop. The USB hubs work for expanding USB ports but not for video output no matter what I've tried.

The first error I receive when plugging in a hub was

```
Display connection might be limited

Make sure the DisplayPort device you're connecting to is supported by your PC
```

but I'm not using DisplayPort.

In device manager I see the following warning on the USB device

```
Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)

A USB port reset request failed.
```

I have tried Windows updates, device driver uninstall / reinstall / update, add / remove device etc. Nothing works.

I am able to connect a separate ASUS portable USB-powered monitor to any of the USB ports and it works (with the correct driver installed first of course), but I can't connect to a proper HDMI or VGA monitor through any adapter.

What could be the problem here that I can't get a video output to the HDMI monitor via USB through a dedicated hub from the laptop? I can't imagine that my USB bus wouldn't support this.

Comment: Not all USB ports support display outputs. Does your laptop specifications include outputting display over USB? If it does, are you using the correct port?

Comment: Even USB-C to HDMI adapters use DisplayPort under the hood. // Please provide the exact model name of your laptop. // Also note that even if your laptop supports it, not all ports on your laptop may. Try different ones.

Comment: @DanielB The laptop is a HP 250 G8 Asteroid. Regarding USB - display support, I am able to connect a separate ASUS portable USB-powered monitor to any of the USB ports and it works (with the correct driver installed first of course). This is what bugs me.. but I can't connect to a proper HDMI or VGA monitor through any adapter.

Comment: Ah, be careful there: USB-C DisplayPort Alt Mode does not require any drivers. Your ASUS monitor may be using _DisplayLink_, which is something different and purely USB. It also is not suitable for high-performance graphics.

Comment: @Engineer999 [Edit] your question instead of submitting temporary comments

Comment: Furthermore, this model name is not enough. It’s something like _2W8X9EA_. Asteroid silver is merely the color.

Comment: @DanielB Ah ok, this is the exact one https://www.alza.cz/EN/hp-250-g8-asteroid-silver-d7050368.htm . So it seems that USB - display output is not even supported

Comment: @DanielB I would've still exprected a hub with its own graphics card to work when interfaced to it, even if the USB on the laptop doesn't support it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### DisplayPort Not Supported

Your laptop does not support DisplayPort over USB-C.

On your laptop the USB-C port and the 2 USB-A ports are all USB 3.2 Gen 1 ports that only support data transfer.

You can however connect additional displays that have DisplayLink support to your USB-C and USB-A ports (such as your Asus portable display) or get a DisplayLink USB hub/adapter and connect generic displays that don't have native DisplayLink support.

[image: DisplayLink Logo]

- Read more about DisplayLink [here](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/small-office/faq)
- example USB hardware with DisplayLink support (hubs, displays, etc.) [here](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/displaylink-products-list?field_displaylink_category_value=usb_adapters)
- See your HP laptop specifications [here](https://support.hp.com/ca-en/document/c06951526)
- Read about DisplayPort over USB-C [here](https://www.displayport.org/displayport-over-usb-c/)

<kbd>HP EliteDisplay E243D DisplayLink</kbd>
<kbd>[image: HP EliteDisplay E243D]</kbd>

<kbd>USB-A Displaylink Adapter</kbd>
<kbd>[image: USB-A DisplayLink]</kbd>

<kbd>USB-C Displaylink Adapter</kbd>
<kbd>[image: USB-C DisplayLink]</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for this. I must say, I learned something new and valuable here.

Comment: I always do too 