# 3 monitors with closed laptop on Lenovo T490 and 2nd gen usb c dock

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, thinkpad, displayport

I was told that I can disable the internal laptop display and hook up all 3 monies: 2 to the dock via DisplayPort and one to laptop side via hdmi. But I haven’t had any luck, the screen just stays black.

See this exchange: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-T400-T500-and-newer-T-series-Laptops/T490-and-Thinkpad-2nd-gen-usb-c-with-3-monitors/m-p/5193046?page=1#5845322

Do I have to go into device manager to disable the laptop display?

And if I unplug laptop from dock won’t I need to disable it again?
Thanks

Comment: I read through the entire answer of the thread you posted and at the bottom they said not supported

Comment: `the screen just stays black` so not single one of your external screen works, regardless of where they are connected to? Do you see them being detected in Device Manager or the corresponding page in Windows Settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

##### Technical Documents are the Gold Standard

If you want to get information you can rely on, you should rely on verified documentation.

Starting with the [ThinkPad_T490 specifications](https://psref.lenovo.com/Product/ThinkPad_T490?tab=spec) refferenced in your forum thread it states there:

> **Monitor Support**
> Supports up to 3 independent displays via **native display** and **2 external monitors**; supports external monitors via HDMI® (up to 4096x2160@24Hz), Thunderbolt™ (up to 4096x2304@60Hz)

Now the person who provided that documentation link went on to write

> if you want to have 3 external monitors connected, you must turn off the laptop's built-in display <sup>[[source](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-T400-T500-and-newer-T-series-Laptops/T490-and-Thinkpad-2nd-gen-usb-c-with-3-monitors/m-p/5193046?page=1#5844897)]</sup>.

They did not however provide any documentation to support this nor any instructions. In my review of the information available for your laptop, I have not yet come across any information that supports the option they suggested.

To the contrary, in the [T490, T590, P43s, and P53s User Guide](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/t490_t590_p43s_p53s_ug_v2_en.pdf) it states you can connect an

> external display to an appropriate video connector on your computer, such as the **HDMI** connector, the **USB-C** connector (USB 3.1 Gen 1), or the **Thunderbolt 3** connector (USB-C).

but it also notes that you **cannot** connect

> external displays to the USB-C connector (USB 3.1 Gen 1) **and** the HDMI connector at the same time. Otherwise, only the external display connected to the USB-C connector (USB 3.1 Gen 1) will work by default.

Your existing Lenovo ThinkPad USB-C Dock Gen 2 can support the following Video Resolutions with ThinkPad **DisplayPort 1.2** USB-C systems:

| Configuration | DisplayPort 1 | DisplayPort 2 | HDMI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 Display | 3840x2160@30Hz or 2560x1440@60hz |  |  |
| 1 Display |  | 3840x2160@30Hz or 2560x1440@60hz |  |
| 1 Display |  |  | 3840x2160@30Hz or 2560x1440@60hz |
| 2 Displays | 1920x1080@60Hz | 1920x1080@60Hz |  |
| 2 Displays |  | 1920x1080@60Hz | 1920x1080@60Hz |
| 2 Displays | 1920x1080@60Hz |  | 1920x1080@60Hz |
| **3 Displays (LCD off)** | **1024x768@60Hz** | **1024x768@60Hz** | **1024x768@60Hz** |

Have you tried limiting your external resolution to 1024x768@60Hz to see if your dock will then support 3 external displays with the lid closed?

ThinkPad docking stations connect via a proprietary port <sup>[[left side port 3](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/pubs/t490/html_en/index.html#t=en%2FLeft_(topic)_T0000698315.html%23ThinkPadEdgeE531Left-sideView-8DA419EA&rhtocid=_3_2)]</sup> which ***may*** provide the possibility of using the [ThinkPad Ultra](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd500173-thinkpad-ultra-docking-station-overview-and-service-parts) Docking Station with 3 external displays.  It isn't clear in the documentation if you would have resolution limited to 1024x768 as with your existing USB-C docking station as much of the limitation is baked into the CPU.  You can discuss with the manufacturer's support to see if running the Ultra with a closed lid will give you what you want at the higher resolutions the **ThinkPad Ultra Docking Station (40AJ)** supports:

| Configuration | DisplayPort 1 (DP1) | HDMI | DisplayPort 2 (DP2) | VGA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Three Displays** | 4096*2160@60Hz | 1920*1080@60Hz | 1920*1080@60Hz |  |
| **Three Displays** | 4096*2160@30Hz | 4096*2160@30Hz |  | 2048*1536@85Hz |

##### [image: DisplayLink]

Lastly, another option to add a third external display is via **DisplayLink** technology. DisplayLink network graphics technology is composed of software installed on your PC and a DisplayLink rendering engine embedded in a display or alternatively in a USB adapter that is connected to a regular display. DisplayLink will allow you to use your USB 2.0 and 3.0 ports to connect additional displays.  It has it's own specifications and limitations so you will need to review information on this technology.  I provided some links below.

---

##### Resources:

- [T490 Hardware Maintenance Manual](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/t490_hmm_en.pdf)
- [ThinkPad T490 Platform Specifications](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/ThinkPad/ThinkPad_T490/ThinkPad_T490_Spec.pdf)
- [ThinkPad T490 Datasheet](https://most.lenovo.com/api/v2/library/pdf/device2pager/ThinkPadT490_T590?locale=en)
- [ThinkPad Ultra Docking Station](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd500173-thinkpad-ultra-docking-station-overview-and-service-parts)
- [Display and Video Output Configurations - ThinkPad  Docking Stations](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd029622#USB-C%20dock%20Gen%202)
- [ThinkPad and Lenovo Docks - Reference Guide](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd014572)
- [Wikipedia: DisplayLink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayLink)
- [synaptics DisplayLink Products](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/displaylink-products)
- [(DisplayLink) My answer on Super User to **USB to HDMI via a hub does not work**](https://superuser.com/a/1758438/1007040)

Comment: OP @relipse, did any of these work?